# Google charts error trying to convert to percentage

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Im trying to add percentage to my chart and centralize the labels, but im getting an a problem. I get 0% in all lines and the left labels do not have the full color. How can I fix it?

My chart image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I58rZ.png

My script:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {
        packages: ["corechart"]
    });
    var dataSet = [
        ['year', 'Muito acima', 'Acima', 'Aprox. Igual', 'Abaixo', 'Muito abaixo', ],
        ['N', 0, 13, 67, 10, 10],
        ['NE', 0, 7, 40, 20, 33],
        ['S', 60, 33, 0, 7, 0],
        ['SE', 0, 13, 53, 33, 0]
    ];
    var dataSet2 = dataSet;
    google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);

    function drawChart2() {
        var sum = new Array();
        for (row = 1; row < dataSet.length; row++) {
            sum[row] = 0;
            for (col = 1; col < dataSet[row].length; col++) {
                sum[row] += dataSet[row][col];
            }
            for (col = 1; col < dataSet[row].length; col++) {
                dataSet2[row][col] = 100 * dataSet[row][col] / sum[row];
            }
        }
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataSet2);
        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
            pattern: '##,##%'
        });
        formatter.format(data, 1);
        formatter.format(data, 2);
        formatter.format(data, 3);
        formatter.format(data, 4);
        formatter.format(data, 5);
        view.setColumns([0, 1, {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },
            2, {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 2,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },
            3, {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 3,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },

            4, {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 4,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            },
            5, {
                calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 5,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"
            }
        ]);
        var options = {
            title: '',
            format: '#,#%',
            fontSize: 12,
            ticks: [{
                v: 13,
                f: '13%'
            }],
            hAxis: {
                suffix: '%',
                ticks: [{
                    v: 0,
                    f: '0%'
                }, {
                    v: 25,
                    f: '25%'
                }, {
                    v: 50,
                    f: '50%'
                }, {
                    v: 75,
                    f: '75%'
                }, {
                    v: 100,
                    f: '100%'
                }]
            }, //Baixo
            vAxis: {
                title: '',
                fontSize: 16,
                format: '#%',
                maxValue: 100
            },
            isStacked: 'true',
            color: '#000',
            colors: ['#4747D1', '#C2C2F0', '#B9CAFF', '#FF9999', '#A32900'],
            legend: {
                position: 'top'
            }
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div2'));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The reason your labels look funny is because there are a bunch of '0%' annotations overlapping them (you can see them easier if you draw the chart with a dark background: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/Zcbcq/).  Hovering over the annotation shows the tooltip for that value; hovering over the bars should show the tooltip for the bar.  It looks like there is a bug, though, in that all of the zero values have their annotations at the axis instead of at the location they should be (`S` in your example should not have an annotation at the axis).  (cont...)

Comment: I think this bug might have been reported already, I'll check with the dev team.

Comment: asgallant Ihve seen that, but like u said there is a bug. Thanks for checking .